# My Jasper Report can no longer find a subreport in the same directory after server move

Tags: jasper-reports

We have moved an application to a new server, so we know that we may have some environment issues. On our old server, Jasper would automatically pick up subreports that were located in the same directory as the report that called them.

Now, we are getting messages like the following:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location : applicationguide_sub_xml.jasper
```

Is there some sort of default path I can pass so that each report will automatically look for subreports in the same directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to change the path inside your main report.
You can change it in the XML tab where you have the follow expression:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["YOURNEWPATHHERE"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being that the .jasper files were not there at all. Which is strange, because I'm calling the Jasper compiler. What I guess is happening is that it only compiles the main jrxml, and looks for the .jasper of the subreport instead of the .jrxml file when compiling. Which is stupid.